# Same key for two users

Tags: ssh

## The problem

I added a new user (`adolfo`) to login through SSH, so I can disable root login. After creating the user, I copied the public key from `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/home/adolfo/.ssh/authorized_keys` because I want to keep using the same key. I guess this is all right. However, if I try to login with `ssh adolfo@<ip-address>`, I get the error `Permission denied (publickey)`.

## Attempts to solve

I have tried following [this answer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/error-permission-denied-publickey-when-i-try-to-ssh?answer=34313) but it didn't work. Though the answer advises to run `chmod 644` on the `authorized_keys` file, I also tried `chmod 600` (which was advised somewhere else). Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference.

## Context

Currently, the relevant file permissions are:

```
$ ls -ld / /home /home/adolfo /home/adolfo/.ssh /home/adolfo/.ssh/authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root   4096 Mar  8 16:45 /
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Mar  7 17:05 /home
drwxr-xr-x  6 adolfo adolfo 4096 Mar  7 17:49 /home/adolfo
drwx------  2 adolfo adolfo 4096 Mar  7 17:09 /home/adolfo/.ssh
-rw-------  1 adolfo adolfo  408 Mar  7 17:09 /home/adolfo/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM no
```

Output of `ssh -vvv adolfo@<ip-address>`:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "thread-safe.nl" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to thread-safe.nl [94.130.181.37] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to thread-safe.nl:22 as 'adolfo'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from thread-safe.nl
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:yghdaf4BIopOULvK2IipaFE6y5wVORoAXV3I6aEB55I
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from thread-safe.nl
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 4 keys from 94.130.181.37
debug1: Host 'thread-safe.nl' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/aochagavia/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fffd694eb40)
debug2: key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/aochagavia/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: please [edit] your question, and add the output of `ssh -vvv adolfo@<ip-address>`

Comment: `chmod 600` on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is correct, not `644`.  The output that Yaron asks for would be helpful.

Comment: Is this with `chmod 600` on that `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file? Did you previously log in as root on this remote system from the exact same account on the local machine (i.e. using the exact same key)?

Comment: Yes, this is with `chmod 600` and I am logging in from the exact same account. In fact, if I take the diff of the log in attempts as `root` and as `adolfo` (up to the authentication error), the only difference is the pointer at which `id_rsa` is loaded (which changes on every login attempt).

Comment: @roaima Just added them :)

Comment: What does the `sshd` daemon write to the log for a login attempt?

Comment: `copied the public key from /root/.ssh/authorized_keys to /home/adolfo/.ssh/authorized_keys`  it isn't the other way around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `adolfo` user was locked for some mysterious reason. I discovered this after Kusalananda asked for the `sshd` log, where I found a line stating that the account was locked. Unlocking it fixed the issue.